# Failed to update lock: configmaps forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Getting the Below error:-

```
Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader-internal-nginx-internal" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx-internal:ingress-nginx-internal" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx-internal"
```

I am using multiple ingress controller in my setup with two different namespaces.
Ingress-Nginx-internal
Ingress-Nginx-external

After installation everything works fine till 15 hrs, getting the above error.

Ingress-nginx-internal.yaml

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml
```

In the above deploy.YAML, I replace. sed 's/ingress-Nginx/ingress-Nginx-internal/g' deploy.yaml

the output of below command:-

```
# kubectl describe cm ingress-controller-leader-internal-nginx-internal -n ingress-nginx-internal
Name:         ingress-controller-leader-internal-nginx-internal
Namespace:    ingress-nginx-internal
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader:
                {"holderIdentity":"ingress-nginx-internal-controller-657","leaseDurationSeconds":30,"acquireTime":"2020-07-24T06:06:27Z","ren...

Data
====
Events:  <none>
```

Service:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-internal-2.0.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-internal
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-internal
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.32.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-internal
  namespace: ingress-nginx-internal
```

Comment: Does it work when you add `get` verb in `Role` manifest posted in answer below?

Answer (score 5):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#multiple-ingress-nginx-controllers)

To run multiple NGINX ingress controllers (e.g. one which serves public traffic, one which serves "internal" traffic) the option `--ingress-class` must be changed to a value unique for the cluster within the definition of the replication controller. Here is a partial example:

```
spec:
  template:
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: nginx-ingress-internal-controller
           args:
             - /nginx-ingress-controller
             - '--election-id=ingress-controller-leader-internal'
             - '--ingress-class=nginx-internal'
             - '--configmap=ingress/nginx-ingress-internal-controller'
```

When you create the ingress resource for internal you need to specify the ingress class as specified above i.e `nginx-internal`

Check the permission of the service account using below command. It it returns `no` then create the role and rolebinding.

```
kubectl auth can-i update configmaps --as=system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx-internal:ingress-nginx-internal -n ingress-nginx-internal
```

RBAC

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: cm-role
  namespace: ingress-nginx-internal
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmap
  verbs:
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cm-rolebinding
  namespace: ingress-nginx-internal
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cm-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx-internal
  namespace: ingress-nginx-internal
```

Comment: These above changes I already did. this error started coming later

Comment: forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount ?? is a part of error

Comment: use the `auth can-i` command to check permission...the reason it came later could be because of either internal ingress resource was not created before or rbac for the service account got deleted somehow

Comment: getting "yes" as an out of auth can-i

Comment: reintsall ingress-nginx-internal, still the same error

Comment: I have updated the `auth can-i` command with verb `update` from `get`. Try that again

Comment: add service template above

Comment: @gauravagnihotri you need to fix the rbac...I have updated the answer with one example..only this may not work.

Comment: kubectl auth can-i update ..says "no" as out put why ?

Comment: @me25 because of rbac...I have added rbac in my answer...apply that yaml

Comment: same error "cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx-internal"

Comment: error : - Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader-internal-nginx-internal" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx-internal:ingress-nginx-internal" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx-internal"

Comment: clusterrole update works, I dont know that right to do that

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu not working, once I deployed ingress-nginx-external it's stopped working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the multi ingress remember to change the resource name in the `Role`.

Answer (score 0):

For default namespace ingress-nginx
rolebinding will looks like
Misstake in example above is that we checking access for **configmaps** but trying to apply role binding for **configmap** here is working sample:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: cm-role
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cm-rolebinding
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cm-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```